# ARCGIS Runtime for .NET: Why am I getting System.ArgumentException 'An item with the same key has already been added'?

Tags: .net, esri, arcgis-runtime

How can I diagnose the above exception? In my code, I roughly do the following:

1. Create an overlay ( `overlay = new GraphicsOverlay()` )
2. Create a set of polygons ( `poly = new Polygon(mappoints)` where `mappoints` is a `PointCollection`)
3. Create a graphic with the polygon geometry and a simple fill symbol for each polygon
   ( `graphic = new Graphic() { Geometry = poly, Symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol() { Color = Colors.Red } }` )
4. Add that graphic to the overlay. ( `overlay.Add(graphic)` )

Then, when something changes, I will call `overlay.Graphics.Clear()`, then repeat steps 2-3.

When I do this, sometimes on the `new Graphic(...)`, I will get the exception (but not every time)

I'm using Esri.ArcGISRuntime version 100.0.0.0.
Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it appears that the problem was that because the `overlay.Graphics.Clear()` was just releasing the objects to the garbage collector that the underlying native objects hadn't yet been disposed.

By forcing the garbage collector to run:

```
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

This caused the objects to be disposed and elimintate the "same key" exception

Comment: received a note from the ESRI folks indicating that this is an error in their code and that my solution is the workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that we'll have fixed in the next update. Forcing GC will work around the issue for now.